# Layer doesn't draw in another one

Tags: c++, drawing, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to make something like custom message box, but the MB layer doesn't want to show up on main layer (scene actually). I've implemented really basic Layer (cocos2d::Layer) with 2 text boxes. I'm adding it to the scene by

```
this->addChild(layer);
```

but actually nothing shows up. I've added music through AudioEngine and it plays, but still I see nothing in main scene.
Cocos2d-x version is 3.16 (latest), also I use latest MSVC on win32.

Comment: 1) [mcve] please. 2) What library is this? 3) What platform is this? 4) What compiler are you using? 5) What C++ standard are you compiling for? In short; don't leave us guessing. Provide *all* relevant details in the question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl 2) cocos2d-x 3.16 3) win32 4) MSVC 2017 5) latest

Comment: Thank you. Now please edit your question and put the information there (where it should have been from the start) rather than in a comment. (Ohh and btw you forgot "1" - the most important one).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add layer as child on the scene once, and then after it add sprites or other nodes to your layer. For example create test scene HelloWorld inherited from cocos2d::Layer:

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
//...
```

Then with factory method define scene creations as:

```
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    auto scene = Scene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

At init method try to add your simple objects to HelloWorld which is inherited from cocos2d::Layer, and Layer is a child of cocos2d::Scene:

```
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto label = Label::createWithTTF("Hello World", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 24);

    // position the label on the center of the screen
    label->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                            origin.y + visibleSize.height - label->getContentSize().height));

    // add the label as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(label, 1);
```

After all those steps run this scene from director:

```
//...
// create a scene. it's an autorelease object
auto scene = HelloWorld::createScene();

// run
director->runWithScene(scene);
//...
```

Comment: I already have a scene with layer, but I want to add one more layer to the scene